# Frequency plots LTspice not lining up with linear plot

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, ltspice

When using the following circuit all the frequency plots I get are incorrect compared to the same frequency. What could be the cause of this?

The internals of this circuit is an opamp and the output does look correct when linear but also does not match when using a frequency plot. Almost nowhere do they line up.

[image: Linear plot]
Frequency plot going to 1 µA at 1 kHz

[image: bode plot]
Frequency plot giving 7 µA at 1 kHz

Any ideas to help me or anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting [good results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD9mx.png) for this simple circuit. Then I look at your 1st picture (you could have made things easier for people trying to ogle your pictures by selecting a more visibe colour for the plots) and I see that the current has a slight offset. That probably means that the results in `.TRAN` are affected somewhere by the polarizations. There are also artifacts, which means that what you call "linear" is not linear, at all. OTOH, the `.AC` analysis *does* make the circuit linear, so it looks like you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: ok, thank you. would there be any way that i could create a bode plot using ltspice if it is not linear?

Comment: You're already doing it. You just have to remember that an `.AC` analysis *linearizes* the circuit, even if it's nonlinear, and it does so around an operating point -- which is calculated based on the DC voltages. The `.AC` analysis doesn't tell you anything about nonlinearities, about DC offsets, about clipping distortion -- it just assumes the circuit is linear. What do you hope to achieve with the `.AC` analysis?

Comment: I want bode plots to show the behavior like our output impedance and output voltage clearly but right now they give incorrect values. for example the bode plot shows a voltage gain starting at 7dB going down to -18dB while analyzing using .tran i find a gain of 30x at all frequencies of audible spectrum

Comment: Perhaps I was being unclear: you are comparing apples and oranges, because in `.TRAN` it shows clear signs of **nonlinearities**, whereas an `.AC` analysis is **perfectly linear**. The only thing that's incorrect is your assumption. LTspice shows the correct result for the given input. It's up to you to know how different analyses perform and how to interpret the results, let alone how to prepare the circuit for analysis.

Comment: For doing bode plots set the source AC parameter to 1, do an AC analysis and measure at the output of the circuit, that will give you a 0 dB reference level.
For measuring output impedance, terminate the input, remove the output load, and put a current source on the output with it's AC parameter set to 1, do an AC analysis and plot the voltage at the current source. Then right click the y-axis and change it to logarithmic, it will give you the impedance in ohms plotted against frequency.